# Start activity vs Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, button, android-activity, menu

I am working at this project and I don't know which way is better to accompish this in terms of optimization.

### I want to create something like that:

[image]

And then when you click on Button 1 other buttons will appear like this

[image]

---

Now, there will be a lot of buttons with a lot of choices, and **minor changes** in my custom toolbar, so I was thinking, **which is the better way to accomplish that?**

I thought of that:

- I can start a new activity for each click
- I can load that into fragments handling them from a Main activity(but actually I don't know how)
- I can load them dynamically (The code won't be compressed like the xml)

Which is the better way? Are there any other options?

Comment: Its bit confusing for me, if possible can you restructure the question. I guess I know the reliable solution, but want to be sure with your requirement

Comment: @MohammedAtif For example, when you click on button1 all the buttons in the view will disappear and others buttons will appear (like when you start a new Activity with an other view and other buttons), if you click on one of them they will disappear too and others will appears and so go on (I want to build this kind of menu).

Comment: In case only number of buttons are changing, based on the user input, you can add the buttons programmatically in the same fragment, in case specal UI arangements are required, you can have different layouts and use same fragment for initializing them and performing operations on them

Comment: And what if I need to change also my toolbar's menu at some point? It will be like Settings > Account, Statistics, Books.
And when the user click on "Account" the toolbar will change and the view will show an activity (or a fragment) with editText

Comment: that is completely different issue, you can have multiple menu xmls in your menu folder and inflate the desired menu or even multiple menus whenever you want

Comment: "Settings > Account, statistics, Books" are the buttons not the menu. So "button1" I was talking about is "Settings", when you click on that, "settings" button will disappear and three buttons will appear: "Account", "statistics" and "books"

Answer (score 0):

The one big advantage of a fragment over activity is that , the code which is used for fragment can be used for different activities.so, it provides reusability of code in application development.

So in your case you can use fragment instead of activity.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to Have one activity, and to put each list of buttons in a different fragment.
this way you have from your activity reference to all fragments, and each fragment has reference to the activity.